# Lazy load the MUI DataGrid column after DataGrid displayed to screen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Is it possible in MUI DataGrid to load a column of data after the MUI DataGrid table is shown on the screen?
These extra columns of data are taking time to fetch from the database, so I want to make this data available after the table is fully loaded to the screen.

For these extra columns of data, I want to make another API call (using react-query) and when the data is ready then I want to show that in the column. Till the time I can show the loader in that column.

I am trying to make an API call in DataGrid's `renderCell` method, but it's affecting the loading time of DataGrid Table.

```
{
  field: "location",
  headerName: "Location",
  flex: 1,
  minWidth: 300,
  renderCell: (params) => (
    // API Call Here
  ),
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

hello Abasaheb Gaware in Mui v5 dataGrid has `loading` props you can pass your react query  variable `.isloading` to `loading` props to show loading until your data is fetching
it's a simple example :

```
<DataGrid
    components={{
      LoadingOverlay: LinearProgress,
    }}
    loading = {yourReactQueryVariable.isloading}
    {...data}
  />
```

Comment: It will show the loading only for the table, I need to show loading only in a particular column as well as fetch data for that column

Answer (score 1):

use *renderCell* instead of *valueGetter*. Here is an example from my use case:

```
renderCell: (params) => {
  // Access the uuid property from params.row
  const uuid = params.row.uuid;

  // Use a loading indicator while fetching market price
  if (isMarketPriceLoading) {
    return (
      <>
        <CircularProgress />
      </>
    );
  }

  // Use an error indicator if fetching market price failed
  if (isMarketPriceError) {
    return "Error";
  }

  // Access marketPriceData using the uuid
  const marketPrice = marketPriceData.find((item) => item.uuid === uuid);
  const sourceCurrency = "IDR";
  const targetCurrency = defaultCurrency;
  const convertedAmount = convertCurrency(
    currencyData,
    sourceCurrency,
    targetCurrency,
    marketPrice.marketValue
  );
  // Return the market price or 'N/A' if not found
  return `${convertedAmount} ${defaultCurrency}`;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

so in that case you will suffer a little :D you must use render cell and write if condition in that render cell until we don't have any data you have to show loading you can use material UI circle progress

```
<CircularProgress color={'inherit'}/>
```

but for additional information you must write the function component and pass data to that function component